# Regarding "pixelated" surface

Tags: materials, faces, lighting

I have recently started using Blender after learning a lot of cool stuff in Andrew's Donut Tutorial.

I am currently in trying to make my first project without following a specific tutorial.

The project I am working on is an entertainment bed for a furniture design class I attend.

I started out creating a UV Sphere and as far as I remember I gave it 32 segments and a radius of 1m.

Afterwards I cut the sphere in half, chose some of the vertices(?) and began to extrude the top and bottom part that extends from sphere to form the desired shape.

The problem is that when I render the image there is some pixelation inside of the sphere. 
[image: Bed - pixelated inside]

The reason it is lit up is because I have put a small strip/piece with an emission material that functions as a light panel on the inside. (as you can see that in the pic below) And the pixelation is even worse on the ins

[image: Bed from inside]

I am thinking this might be because I have cut a sphere in half and normally you would only see the outside of the sphere.

But is there a way I can fix this without having to model the bed again?

On beforehand thanks!

(Other feedback on the bed & project is also welcomed)

Comment: Is the shading set to smooth?

Comment: Yes, so unfortunately that's not the problem.. :/